# ValueError: Error executing sum_product(): The last argument value must be a variable or expression object if no 'index' option is specified

Tags: python, pyomo, sumproduct

The pyomo gives  the following error message when I try to add the below constraint to my model:

```
ValueError: Error executing sum_product(): The last argument value must be a variable or expression object if no 'index' option is specified
```

The constraint I am adding to the model:

```py
import pyomo.environ as pe

model.Cons.add(2900<=pe.summation(A[i] * (B[i] * model.z[i+1]+C[i] * (D[i]-(E[i] + K[i] * (model.qgl[i+1]-F[i]))+(np.ones(u)-model.z[i+1]) * G[i])) for i in (np.arange(u))))
```

The capital letters represent the available parameters. I have two variables in the model: binary variable `model.z` and another variable `model.qgl`.

When I replace the `pe.summation` with `sum`, it gives the following error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I don’t know what causes this error. Can you please share your thoughts and experience about this matter?

Comment: Please supply a working example

Comment: The model is too long. Therefore, I didn't share it.

Comment: It's hard to help, without being able to see the error. The errormessage means you are comparing an array with a single value. Try simplifying the expression further (look at the result of the sum)